# AS3 convert a nested array to JSON object

Tags: json, actionscript-3

There is the native JSON.stringify method, but this is NOT what I need

I need to convert the following

```
[['user1',150],['user2',270],['user3',500]]
```

to a proper JSON object

```
{"user1" : 150,
"user2" : 270,
"user3" : 500
}
```

Comment: So you want to convert a perfectly good JSON array into a JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok answering my own question

```
var jsonOb={}


var L:int=testArray.length;

for(var i:int=0;i<L;i++){

    jsonOb[testArray[i][0]]=testArray[i][1]

}




trace('jsonOb=='+jsonOb+ ' and JSON.stringify(jsonOb) = '+JSON.stringify(jsonOb));
```